# Apache Nifi with Web Service

Tags: web-services, apache-nifi, office365api, project-online

I'm trying to access a https site from Apache Nifi that has informations that I'm intrested at. The problem is it needs authentification to access the site.

With InvokeHTTP in Apache Nifi, we only can have the 'Basic Authentification' that I don't even know what stands for, but when inserting my logging identification, nothing changes. and I have a Access denied to that site (

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
   <m:code>-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException</m:code>
   <m:message xml:lang="en-US">Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

).

I've been looking for answers about a week ago, and I can't seem to find the answer anywhere, 
That's why I'm asking you guys for help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "trying to access"... in what? from where? What did you try so far?

Comment: your site requires authentification. and you have to know a way how they do this. as soon as you tagget this question office365api here is an official doc to access office365 api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/use-outlook-rest-api#register-and-authenticate-your-app

Comment: hey @OlafKock , I have edited my question, I think know you would be able to get it.

Thank you for responding!

Comment: @daggett I get 403 FORBIDDEN
Thank you for responding!